# Add row to dataframe based on condition of previous row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
class <- c(3,0,3,0,0)
value <- c(50,50,70,30,100)
days <- c(3,3,2,2,1)
mydata <- data.frame(class, value, days)
```

What I need is for each day to have both classes represented - so if there is no class 3 on a given day (in this example, day 1) I'd like to add a row where `class = 3` and `value = 0` and `day = 1`. My real data is more complicated, because there are varying numbers of rows for each day (and many more days than 3), and many other columns (but for which it would be fine to enter `NA`). This doesn't seem like too complicated a problem, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the code. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, I have amended it and it should no longer give errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` you can use `complete`:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>%
  complete(days, class, fill = list(value = 0))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   days class value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0   100
2     1     3     0
3     2     0    30
4     2     3    70
5     3     0    50
6     3     3    50
```

**Data**

```
mydata <- structure(list(class = c(3, 0, 3, 0, 0), value = c(50, 50, 70, 
30, 100), days = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: That was amazingly fast. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, we can do

```
out <- merge(expand.grid(lapply(mydata[c('class', 'days')],
         unique)), mydata, all.x = TRUE)
out$value[is.na(out$value)] <- 0
out
#  class days value
#1     0    1   100
#2     0    2    30
#3     0    3    50
#4     3    1     0
#5     3    2    70
#6     3    3    50
```

NOTE: No packages used

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[CJ(class, days, unique = TRUE),
     on = .(class, days)][is.na(value), value := 0][]
#   class value days
#1:     0   100    1
#2:     0    30    2
#3:     0    50    3
#4:     3     0    1
#5:     3    70    2
#6:     3    50    3
```

---

Or using `crossing/left_join` from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tidyr::crossing(class = unique(mydata$class),
       days = unique(mydata$days)) %>% 
  left_join(mydata) %>%
  mutate(value = replace_na(value, 0))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  class  days value
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     1   100
#2     0     2    30
#3     0     3    50
#4     3     1     0
#5     3     2    70
#6     3     3    50
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(class = c(3, 0, 3, 0, 0), value = c(50, 50, 70, 
30, 100), days = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```